# Cookie consent message needed for web game high score?

Tags: cookie, gdpr, eu-cookie-law

I'm making an online word game and I want to use a cookie to store the user's high score so it will always show it when they play the game, not just for the session. To comply with the EU GDPR do I need a cookie consent message for that? It will only be storing the high score, no name or email address or anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is no. [This page](https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/how-the-gdpr-affects-cookie-policies) says

> Not all cookies are used in a way that could identify users, but the majority are and will be subject to the GDPR.

That sounds like if there is no personal identifying information involved, such as just a high score, then GDPR doesn't apply.